# Sphinx Search - Can't search in Hebrew?

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I have some problems with using queries in Hebrew. I tried this:
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=1431

But for some reason only one letter queries returns results..
For example: "מ" returns 10 results when "מכ" returns 0...

What could be the problem?

Comment: You should trouble-shoot if you're doing everything right with the encodings and then actually you should check first if the hebrew texts get indexed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to read [Using Sphinx search engine with Chinese, Japanese, and Korean language documents](http://www.ivinco.com/blog/using-sphinx-search-engine-with-chinese-japanese-and-korean-language-documents/)